# jQuery common code...MVC3 App

Tags: javascript, jquery, encapsulation

I have a C#.NET MVC3 web app and I have some common jQuery functionality across my pages and want to modularize it.  I don't know how to do this.  Below is an example of the code I'm using.  You will notice several controls have functions assigned to events.  Each View I have will do this, BUT the controls (and number of controls) will be different.  There may be 1 control that needs the event added to or there may be 10.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Description").keyup(function () {
        disableEnableSave();
    });
    $("#DueDate").change(function () {
        disableEnableSave();
    });
    $("#EndDate").keyup(function () {
        disableEnableSave();
    });
});
```

Below is the disableEnableSave() code.  Similar issue, inside that code, there may 1 control to work against or 10.

```
    function disableEnableSave() {
        var text = $("#Description").val();
        var text1 = $("#DueDate").val();
        var text2 = $("#EndDate").val();
        var textlength = text.length;
        var textlength1 = text1.length;
        var textlength2 = text2.length;
        if (textlength > 0 && textlength1 > 0 && textlength2 > 0) {
            $("#thePageSubmit").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
        else {
            $("#thePageSubmit").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
        document.title = document.title.replace("*", "");
        document.title = document.title + "*";
        return true;
    }
```

I am not a jQuery or JavaScript expert but I gotta think there's a way to encapsulate this in a .js file and pass in some parameters.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/g3azJ/3/

```
$.fn.disableFalseInput = function(list) {
    var _this = $(this),
        required = $(list);

    required .bind("keyup change", function() {
        var available = true;
        $.each(required , function(k, v) {
            if (v.value.length == 0) {
                available = false;
                return false;
            }
        });
        if (available) {
            _this.removeAttr("disabled")
        } else {
            _this.attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    }).first().trigger("keyup");
}
```

Define the button that needs some inputs as required:

```
$("#thePageSubmit").disableFalseInput("#Description, #DueDate, #text2");
```

`#thePageSubmit` is the submit button that will be disabled, and the parameter are the fields required. This can be used on each button, or whatever you got.

Comment: @Niels...that's nice!!  real nice....I'll give it a rip.  I can put the disableFalseInput() function inside a seperate .js file for use by all pages...yes?

Comment: Yes you can! If you use the `.disableFalseInput()` after document ready. I won't be a problem.